# waking up a background agent in windows mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way that one can wake up an application or a background agent in response to a notification or SMS being sent to a Windows mango device?

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you not choose when a background agent or application runs, but there are no APIs for accessing SMS data.